# I need to do the piglatin exercise in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I need to check if a word starts with a vowel or consonant. For words starting with a vowel I need to ad "ay" to the end of the word. This part was easy. I managed it like this:

```
def translate string
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
   if vowels.include? (string[0])
   string +'ay'
  else
   *the consonant part goes here*
  end
end
```

I need help with the syntax for the consonant part. If a word begins with a consonant sound, move it to the end of the word, and then add an "ay" sound to the end of the word.
Here's what I'm trying to do in the else part of my if statement:

```
consonant = string(0)
new_word = string - string(0)
pig_latin_word = new_word << consonant << "ay"
```

Thank you.

Comment: string[0] is not string(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want to do with `string(0)` is to get the first character in the string, in such case you'd need to do it with square brackets `string[0]`.

When you do `string - string[0]` to take out the first character from the string, and assign this to a variable called `new_word` then you get an `undefined method`-'`error, that's because you can't use`-` for such operation, you could take a certain number of characters from the string when there's no the first one and assign it to that variable like:

```
p 'the'[1..-1]
# => "he"
```

So that gives you the characters from the string in a range from 1 up to the last element (`-1`).

I could say when you do `pig_latin_word = new_word << consonant << "ay"`, it'd be easier if you just `return` the last evaluated expression, this way and as you're not using the `pig_latin_word` variable, you can interpolate your variables with the `"ay"` ending and this will be what the methods return in the case the the first character of the string isn't a lowercase vowel, so, something like this would make your code work:

```
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
if vowels.include? (string[0])
  string +'ay'
else
  consonant = string[0]
  new_word = string[1..-1]
  "#{new_word}#{consonant}ay"
end
```

But still I'm not sure, do you have to validate for every word within a sentence being passed?. In such case that would add "ay" just to the last word of the string, if a single word is passed then it works, but with a sentence like `'the quick brown fox'` then it'd return `"he quick brown foxtay"`.

And/or in the case you check if the first character of the string is a vowel, you check just for lowercase vowel, in the case it'd be an uppercase vowel, that would make it look like:

```
p translate('apple')
# => "appleay"
p translate('Apple')
# => "ppleAay"
```

It moves your `A` first character to the end of the string and the adds `ay`.

What you could do is to `split` your string being passed as argument - this way if it's a sentence, you get every word, and if is a single word, then it'd work too - and check if every of the first character of them match with a vowel, uppercase and lowercase, and if so then you return just the `word` plus `"ay"`, and if it's not, then you get every character from the word, make from this an array, and rotate them one character, this way if the string being passed is `'the quick brown fox'` you get `"het uickq rownb oxf"`, then as it's an array, you join them and add the `ay` ending, and then over your "mapped" string, you use join to join each word with a whitespace, something like:

```
def translate(string)
  string.split.map do |word|
    if /\A[aeiou]/i.match(word)
      "#{word}ay"
    else
      "#{word.chars.rotate(1).join}ay"
    end
  end.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: rubydoc says [`String#rotate`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/String%3Arotate), but running in Ruby 2.4.1 I got `undefined method 'rotate' for string:String`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I just needed to test for a single, lowercase consonant first. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution would be to to concatenate slices of the string, using same syntax as you would with an array, with 'ay' in a neat one liner:

```
string[1..-1] + string[0] + 'ay'
```